# How to setup ApolloServer and SubscriptionServer to use http and ws in graphql

Tags: websocket, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-server, graphql-subscriptions

I have been following the docs for [here](https://github.com/apollographql/subscriptions-transport-ws) and [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-subscriptions/setup/) to implement the `subscriptions-transport-ws` plugin. My big confusion is differentiating the graphql url for `http://` and `ws://`. In the examples above it looks like `ApolloServer` is getting replaced by `SubscriptionServer`. But if I only want to use websockets in special circumstances, then don't I still need both? Or is `SubscriptionServer` handling both at once and doing some magic in the background which figures out which one to use based on whether or not a subscription is called?

Answer (score 1):

`apollo-server` combines several tools such as: [graphql-tools](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/blob/main/packages/apollo-server/src/exports.ts#L1), [graphql-subscriptions](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/blob/main/packages/apollo-server/src/exports.ts#L2), [graphql-upload](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/blob/main/packages/apollo-server-core/src/processFileUploads.ts#L10), provide some [custom errors](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/blob/main/packages/apollo-server/src/exports.ts#L11), and use [express.js](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/blob/main/packages/apollo-server/src/index.ts#L98) web framework as its default web server implementation.

`subscriptions-transport-ws` is a GraphQL WebSocket server and client to facilitate GraphQL queries, mutations, and subscriptions over WebSocket.

> subscriptions-transport-ws is an extension for GraphQL, and you can use it with any GraphQL client and server (not only Apollo).

So, `ApolloServer`  is **NOT** replaced by `SubscriptionServer`.

Without using `ApolloServer`, you need to set up GraphQL HTTP server using `express.js`, `graphqlExpress`, `graphiqlExpress`, `cors` middlewares by yourself. Like this [official sample](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-subscriptions/setup/#subscriptionserver) does.

If you want to create a subscription server, you need to create HTTP server and pass it to `SubscriptionServer` constructor for [initing and connecting WebSocket server to http](https://github.com/apollographql/subscriptions-transport-ws/blob/747da638488a35fb8c1d11d67d1d34a47e305329/src/server.ts#L135)

Comment: Please have in mind that subscriptions-transport-ws is not actively maintained:
„The subscriptions-transport-ws library is not being actively maintained. It is recommended that you use the graphql-ws library instead. For details read the GraphQL over WebSockets announcement“